# Откат транзакции в PHP (MariaDB, InnoDB) при нескольких параллельных транзакциях изменяющих одинаковые поля

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb, innodb

У меня есть несколько PHP кодов с PDO транзакциями, измняющими одинаковые поля в базе данных. Коды могут запускаться в разные моменты времени. Если произойдёт ситуация, когда нужно будет откатить некоторую транзакцию, но во время выполнения этой транзакции, другая уже успела изменить поле, которое нужно откатить, то что вообще произойдёт?
Уровень изоляции - REPEATABLE READ. Хотя это особого отношения к вопросу, кажется, не должно иметь. П.С. И я не использую FOR UPDATE, чтобы другие транзакции могли спокойно менять нужные им поля во время выполнения других транзакций.

Comment: Опишите более подробно, что вы делаете. Упоминание for update говорит мне, что вы сначала читаете запись, а потом ее меняете. Делать этого без for update вообще нельзя ни при каких условиях. Вне зависимости от того будет что то откатываться или нет в середину между select и update что то может пролезть. Но если update уже начался, то там ниже ответили ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> другая уже успела изменить поле, которое нужно откатить

Эта ситуация просто невозможна. Если транзакция обновила строку - то до завершения этой транзакции все последующие транзакции желающие изменить эту строку будут ждать. Именно потому что неизвестно, что с этой строкой происходит и как она должна выглядеть: то ли транзакция откатится и надо брать что было до неё, то ли зафиксируется и надо брать то что стало, то ли транзакция ещё что-то поменяет в этой строке (потому что имеет право).

Разница между тем, завершилась транзакция фиксацией или откатом будет лишь в том, какую версию строки увидит следующая транзакция из очереди блокировок.

Comment: получается, что deadlock возможен в таких случаях и его нужно предвидеть после каждого UPDATE, т.к. строка закрывается и на чтение и на запись?

Comment: deadlock в транзакционных системах всегда возможен, если две транзакции берут блокировки в разном порядке. При большом старании можно словить deadlock из транзакций в один запрос каждая. Конкурентное чтение обычно разрешено, innodb ведь mvcc. Хотя это mysql, там много нелогичного поведения, так что не уверен.